# Ubuntu 18.04 Hyper-V guest can access the internet but can't be accessed with ssh from host

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualization, hyper-v

I set up an Ubuntu 18.04 vm with Hyper-V on a Windows 10 machine. The vm has internet access via the default virtual network switch, but I'm not able to ping it or ssh from the host using its eth0 IPv4 address that I got from ifconfig.

VM IP: 172.28.141.148

Host IP: 172.25.153.63

I set up the virtual switch with the default virtual switch. I believe it was already configured.

Comment: How did you setup HyperV switch? What's PC's IP and VM IP?

Comment: @Hannel I updated the post.

Comment: @Hannel Thanks for the help! I am now trying to ssh to the host with the IP listed in 'lo' instead of 'eth0', and my connection is being refused by vm host. This is an improvement over the 'no route to host'. I'm able to ping the vm now using the lo IP.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the information you provide you might have a bad NAT setup because if done right you should be able to SSH. Just create a new NAT on the HyperV, set VM to use new NAT, and see if you get the same issue.

On host using PowerShell run;

```
$switchName = "InternalNAT"
New-VMSwitch -Name $switchName -SwitchType Internal
New-NetNat –Name $switchName –InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix "192.168.0.0/24"
$ifIndex = (Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.name -like "*$switchName)"}).ifIndex
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.1 -InterfaceIndex $ifIndex -PrefixLength 24
```

If you do no have DHCP on the host you will need to set IP manually on guest VM to an IP in the NAT range.

Then you should be able to SSH into VM from Host on port 22

[image]

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization